# Can I use the same dataset and execute 2 different stored procedures and save into 2 datatables?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Would like to use the same dataset for the result sets from 2 different sql stored procedures (which both return a single set).  Or is it just easier to change  commandtype.text("exec my_sp1; exec my_sp2;") ?  Would like to keep CommandType.StoredProcedure ...  What is the best way to handle this?

```
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
cmdSQL1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdSQL1.CommandText = ("my_sp1")
cmdSQL2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdSQL2.CommandText = ("my_sp2") 
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL1)
da.Fill(ds)  ...   ?
```

Comment: This is not related to sql-server or database. so I removed those tags. Please use tags properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL1)
da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
da.SelectCommand = cmdSQL2
da.Fill(ds, "Table2")
```